# Why not to use parentheses in front of name of an external function while calling it from addEventListner method in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I am new to javascript and unable to understand one concept-

Why don't we use parentheses in front of name of an **external function**, while calling it(that particular function) by **addEventListener** method, in **JavaScript**.

```
For Example-
.addEventListener('click', myExternalFunction);


and not-
.addEventListener('click', myExternalFunction());
```

Comment: Because you don't want to invoke it at the time at which you attach the listener - you only want it to be invoked when the listener triggers. Also, `addEventListner` spelling matters in programming.

Comment: I understand that it will be invoked at the time of execution automatically.
But why does it behave like this?

Comment: That's just the way it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whenever you are adding Event Listeners in any of the language you provide the delegates / Function Pointers.

They are not the actual function call they just point to the function and when the event actually occurs it will call that particular function.

This is how Delegates / Function Pointers works.